# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysql could not be converted to string

Tags: php

How to remove catchable error in php.I working on php code get catchable error.CAn some one help me to remove this remove.I am using class call in other file when I make its object I got error.I see this is simple error can that is I call to function mysql_coonect but still problem error.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
@ PHP5 Mysql-klasse 
@ Copyright by Web Communication World (www.wccw.in)
@ Diese Klasse darf frei unter diesem Vermerk eingesetzt,
verändert und weitergegeben werden
@ Weitere Klassen, sind auf www.wccw.in Kostenlos erhältlich
Verwendete Funktionen:
@ mysql_connect
@ mysql_select_db
@ mysql_error
@ mysql_query
@ mysql_fetch_array
@ mysql_fetch_assoc
@ mysql_fetch_object
@ mysql_fetch_row
@ mysql_num_rows
@ mysql_real_escape_string
@ mysql_free_result
@ mysql_insert_id
@ mysql_close
@ htmlspecialchars
@ trigger_error
*/
class mysql
{
private $host     = ''; 
private $user     = '';
private $passwort     = ''; 
private $dbname     = '';
private $last_injection = '';
private $conn_id = null;
public function __construct($host, $user, $passwort, $dbname)
{
$this->host     = $host;
$this->user     = $user;
$this->passwort = $passwort;
$this->dbname     = $dbname;
$this->connect_mysql();
return($this->conn_id);
}
private function connect_mysql()
{
$this->conn_id = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->passwort);
if($this->conn_id === false)
{
$message  = "Verbindung zur Datenbank nicht m&ouml;glich.<br />\n";
$message .= "Mysql-fehlermeldung: <br />\n";
$message .= mysql_error();
trigger_error($message);
} 
else 
{
$this->select_db();
}
}
private function select_db()
{
$select = mysql_select_db($this->dbname,$this->conn_id);
if($select === false)
    {
        $message  = "Die angegebene Datenbank \"".$this->dbname."\" 
existiert nicht.<br />\n";
        $message .= "Mysql-fehlermeldung: <br />\n";
        $message .= mysql_error();
        trigger_error($message);
    }
}
public function query($sqlcode)
{
    $this->last_injection = mysql_query($sqlcode);
           if($this->last_injection === false)
        {
            $message  = "Fehler bei dem Ausf&uuml;hren eines Mysql-codes!<br />\n";
            $message .= "Mysql-Code: " . htmlspecialchars($sqlcode, ENT_QUOTES) . 
            "<br />\n";
            $message .= "Mysql-fehlermeldung:<br />\n";
            $message .= mysql_error();
            trigger_error($message);
        }
       return($this->last_injection);
}
public function array_result($sql = NULL, &$row = '')
{
    $inc = '';
    if($sql === NULL)
    {
        $inc = $this->last_injection;
        } else {
        $inc = $sql;
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($inc);
    return($row);
}
public function row_result($sql = NULL, &$row = '')
{
    $inc = '';
    if($sql === NULL)
    {
        $inc = $this->last_injection;
        } else {
        $inc = $sql;
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($inc);
    return($row);
}
public function object_result($sql = NULL, &$row = '')
{
    $inc = '';
    if($sql === NULL)
    {
        $inc = $this->last_injection;
        } else {
        $inc = $sql;
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($inc);
    return($row);
}
public function assoc_result($sql = NULL, &$row = '')
{
    $inc = '';
    if($sql === NULL)
    {
        $inc = $this->last_injection;
        } else {
        $inc = $sql;
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($inc);
    return($row);
}
public function num_result($sql = NULL)
{
    $inc = '';
    if($sql === NULL)
    {
        $inc = $this->last_injection;
        } else {
        $inc = $sql;
    }
    $num = mysql_num_rows($inc);
     return($num);
}
public function sql_string($string)
{
    return(mysql_real_escape_string($string));
}
public function free_result($sql = NULL)
{
    $inc = '';
    if($sql === NULL)
    {
        $inc = $this->last_injection;
        } else {
        $inc = $sql;
    }
     mysql_free_result($inc);
}
public function result($set = 0, $field = 0, $sql = NULL, &$row = '')
{
    $inc = '';
    if($sql === NULL)
    {
        $inc = $this->last_injection;
        } else {
        $inc = $sql;
    }
    $row = mysql_result($result, $set, $field);
    return($row);
}
public function insert_id(&$row = '')
{
    $row = mysql_insert_id();
    return($row);
}
public function close_connect()
{
    mysql_close($this->conn_id);
}
}
class db extends mysql
{
private static $_instance;
public static function getInstance()
{
if( self::$_instance == null )
{
self::$_instance = new db('localhost', 'root', '', 'qcore');
}
return self::$_instance;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: which line is the error

Comment: <?php  $user = NEW mysql('localhost','root','','qcore');
        $user->passwort
      //print($user);?>
WHen I make object of mysql class I gor error

Comment: its complaining about a string, did you echo anything, you need to show the code where you use the class itself

Comment: Please update your question with the full error message and the line of code where it occurs.